# Erro ao fazer login com o Facebook em Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, integração

Tenho um aplicativo que possue login com o Facebook, mas alguns dias atrás esse recurso parou de funcionar e agora exibe a seguinte mensagem que se encontra na  imagem em anexo, deletei o aplicativo que criei no Facebook, criei as chaves hashes novamente, mas continua ocorrendo o erro abaixo, alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa questão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisar confirmar la no dashboard do facebook se o package da aplicação está correto, e vale lembrar que o hash pra debug é diferente do hash pra release

Comment: Muito obrigado  @LeonardoDias, eu conferi o pacote e gerei uma 
"keyhash Produção", mas continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: estava com o mesmo problema e ma verdade tinha gerado de forma errada, este video me explicou exatamente como fazer diferente de outros, tente fazer o passo a passo , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=587P99xRh0U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, conseguiu resolver o problema? Essa `key hash` é para ser utilizada em desenvolvimento?

Ocorre porque a gente precisa informar essa `key hash` nas configurações do nosso aplicativo no site do Facebook Developer. O dispositivo acabou gerando essa `key hash`.

Para mim também apareceu essa mensagem, peguei o `key hash` que estava aparecendo erro e adicionei nas configurações do aplicativo.

[image: Imagem key hash desenvolvimento]

Answer (score 0):

Caso você gere um hash e mesmo assim não funcione, ceritifique-se que seja a versão **openssl-0.9.8e**, pois tive um problema similar, e rosolveu com essa versão

comando para gerar o hash no windows pelo prompt:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\**SEU_USER**\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

obs: trocar os caminhos dos arquivos de acordo com os do seu sistema

depois é só adicionar no console do facebook